# Sprite draw-order in libgdx

Tags: libgdx, sprites, spritebatch, draw-order

From other frameworks I know methods for easy ordering sprites within a spritebatch (to determine if a sprite has to be drawn in front or behind another sprite). For example in MonoGame/XNA this is called `Sprite.depth` or Pyglet has its `OrderedGroups`.

But I cannot find anything like that in libgdx. I've read that libgdx' scene2d has something like that but I don't want to use that as I use a entity system (ashley) and want to keep rendering separeted from the other logic.

What is the appropriate way to set the draw-order of libgdx sprites?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct that libGDX doesn't contain any sort of built-in support for rendering sprites in a certain order. (If it's there, I haven't seen it, and I've been using libGDX for a number of years.)

What I do is create a `SpriteComponent` class that wraps the `Texture` object and emits `x`, `y`, and `z` attributes.

Then in my draw method, I sort all `SpriteComponents` by `z` (ascendingly) and draw them -- so lower-Z items draw first, then higher-Z items on top.

Comment: So libgdx sprites and textures are just drawn in the same order in which I call their draw methods? (I haven't done very much with that framework yet, I'm only evaluating so far)

Comment: That's correct. In that sense, you have full control over the drawing order. There just isn't a built-in Z ordering of sprites.

Answer (score 4):

For normal cases, sprite order is determined by the `Spritebatch.draw()` call order. If this is the case:

```
spritebatch.draw(apple);
spritebatch.draw(mango);
```

then `apple` will be drawn first and then `mango` will be drawn on top of that. So `mango` will overlap `apple`.